# Why does Python Flask-User with MongoDB throw an error related to the non-MongoDB version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask

Sorry about the subject - it's pretty vague.

Anyway, I'm trying to integrate Flask-User into my Flask app.  The integration has worked from a registration perspective i.e. users can sign up, receive the confirmation email then confirm their account.

That process also automatically signs the user in.  This has all been done without using the sign-in form.

However, if the user signs out and tries to sign back using the sign in form, I get this error:

```
builtins.AttributeError
    AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'email_confirmed_at'
```

I know what that means i.e. the User model doesn't have an 'email_confirmed_at' property, but that's a field that is only used in the Flask-User quickstart apps that use Flask-SQLAlchemy.  You can see that in the [documentation](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_app.html).

I'm following the [MongoDB App](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mongodb_app.html) example, and there's no mention of that property anywhere.

Can anyone suggest why this might be?  The "TroubleShooting" section of the MongoDB example just says TBD.

Additional info:

Here is the User model for one of the SQLAlchemy examples:

```
# Define the User data-model.
# NB: Make sure to add flask_user UserMixin !!!
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')

    # User authentication information. The collation='NOCASE' is required
    # to search case insensitively when USER_IFIND_MODE is 'nocase_collation'.
    email = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email_confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # User information
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles')
```

And here is the User model for the MongoDB example:

```
# Define the User document.
# NB: Make sure to add flask_user UserMixin !!!
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)

    # User authentication information
    username = db.StringField(default='')
    password = db.StringField()

    # User information
    first_name = db.StringField(default='')
    last_name = db.StringField(default='')

    # Relationships
    roles = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=[])
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.  Silly to not think of it before, but I just had to modify the User model to include the `email_confirmed_at` property.

It is a little weird that it fails this way "out of the box" but it does work now.

New bits added:

```
# Email confirmation date & time
email_confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
```